# Listing WooCommerce purchases in Python

Tags: python, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Is there any way to make a Python program that checks if a purchase has been made on a WooCommerce site and display the order in a string?

Comment: See the documention: [WooCommerce Rest API (python)](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?python#introduction) and [A Python wrapper for the WooCommerce REST API](https://pypi.org/project/WooCommerce/)

Comment: Interesting thing. I have no knowledge of python but I would suggest doing it the other way: hook wordpress/woocommerce into posting the order data to your python app.